# Runtime errors with User-defined conversion functions accessed via generic methods

Tags: .net, generics, c++-cli

I am trying to implement a generic function which wraps an ancient library on the C++ side. The old code predates templates, and there are many functions of the form fooInt, fooDouble, fooObject etc. Ideally, this function call can be done with a single generic function, foo. I ran into some issues trying to implement this, and have reproduced my issues with this very basic example:

```
ref class bar
{
public:
    System::UInt32 myint = 0;
    bar(System::UInt32 in){ myint = in; }
    operator System::UInt32()
    {
        return myint;
    }
};
generic <typename T> T foo(System::UInt32 value)
{
    auto t = %bar(value);
    return (T) t;
}
int main()
{
    //=======WORKS=======
    auto t = %bar(123);
    System::Console::WriteLine((System::UInt32)t);
    //=======DOESN'T WORK :(=======
    System::Console::Write(foo<System::UInt32>(123));
    return 0;
}
```

When run, this code will produce the error `An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException'` upon reaching the `return (T) t;` statement in `foo()`.

This code would work fine with templates, however, as this is intended to be used in .NET environments, those would not be exposed outside of the library and thus are not a solution to my woes. Any ideas?

Comment: Two things: A) Please tell us what runtime error you're getting; don't make us guess. B) Please note that `ref struct` in C++/CLI is a _reference_ type, not a value type. To get the same object as a C# struct, use `value struct`.

Comment: My apologies- I did not realize I neglected to include the actual error! As for your second point, I am under the impression that to do user-defined conversion functions to value types, the struct needs to be a reference type, as if the struct were a value type it would error upon attempting to make the cast `(System::UInt32)t`.

Comment: Since you have the equivalent to a C# `class`, I highly recommend that you make it `ref class` in C++/CLI. It compiles to _exactly_ the same the same thing as `ref struct`, and there's no confusion as to what your intent was.

Comment: This is not entirely true: A `struct` has default visibility of `public`, whereas a `class` has a default visibility of `private`. Regardless, I have changed the example, as I agree with the notion behind the request.

Comment: Conversion operators are only considered at compile time, not at runtime.  You can only do this with templates, not generics.

Comment: That was what I feared. As stated, templates would not work in this case because they aren't visible on the .NET side, so an alternative solution is still necessary.

Answer (score 0):

A valid workaround was to make a method in `bar` which takes in a `System::Type^` and returns an object of that type, upcast to an `Object^`:

```
ref class bar
{
public:
    System::UInt32 myint = 0;
    bar(System::UInt32 in){ myint = in; }
    Object^ get(System::Type^ in)
    {
        if (in == System::UInt32::typeid)
            return myint;
        //Add more types here.
        else return nullptr;
    }
};
generic <typename T> T foo(System::UInt32 value)
{
    auto t = %bar(value);
    return (T)t->get(T::typeid);
}
int main()
{
    System::Console::Write(foo<System::UInt32>(123));
    return 0;
}
```

Note that I removed the user-defined conversion function for brevity's sake, but it would be required if you wished to do static casting as shown in the question.

Comment: This still feels rather inelegant, I'd love to see a better approach.